# Compiled solidity contract run out of gas on deployment

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

I have a solidity contract that compiles ok (0.5.1 compiler version), but it runs out of gas if I deploy the whole of it. If I comment some of the external methods of the contract, it compiles and deploys ok. I think the problem is not in the methods theirselves as I can comment any of them separately and it works.

I'm doing all this with **truffle** on a local network with **ganache**:

```
truffle migrate --network development --reset
```

The error:

```
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"PPA" ran out of gas (using a value you set in your network config or deployment parameters.)
   * Block limit:  0x6691b7
   * Gas sent:     6721975
```

My truffle-config.js:

```
[...]
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "http://127.0.0.1:7545")
      },
      network_id: 5777
    }
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.5.1"        
    }
  }
};
```

Any clue what's going on?

Comment: can you share your smart contract? chances are that it is throwing an exception somewhere

Comment: Try it on remix to see how much gas it takes to deploy it

Answer (score 0):

You can and should define the provided GAS in the truffle-config.json, depending on the limitations of the used blockchain (ganache has the default gas limit of 0x6691b7 or 6721975) and the size of your contract binaries.

Try something like this:

```
[...]
module.exports = {
    networks: {
        development: {
            provider: function() {
                return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "http://127.0.0.1:7545")
            },
            network_id: 5777,
            gas: 6721975 
        }
    },
    compilers: {
        solc: {
            version: "0.5.1"
    }
    }
};
```

In the case this does not work, you may increase the GAS limit to ganache.